# Using generics to get class methods via reflection in Java

Tags: java, json, reflection

I am trying to create a utility class that accepts any type of POJO, and converts that POJO into a JSON object. It should use Java reflections and annotations to look through certain getter methods and create a key, value JSON element based on that.

I am trying to use generics to do this, but it doesn't seem to work. Is this not possible?

I want to pass a class object as a parameter and retrieve the correct class methods if possible.

Code I have written so far:

```java
package com.jr.freedom.util;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

public class JsonParserUtil {
    private static final String GET_CHAR_SEQUENCE = "get";

    public static <T> JSONObject toJsonObject(Class<T> classObject) {
        // get Method names with @JsonElement included
        Method methods[] = classObject.class.getDeclaredMethods();

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
                String key = methods[i].getName();
                System.out.println(key);
                if (methods[i].isAnnotationPresent(JsonElement.class) && key.contains(GET_CHAR_SEQUENCE)) {
                    key.replaceFirst(GET_CHAR_SEQUENCE, "");
                    jsonObject.put(key, methods[i].invoke(classObject));
                }
            }
            return jsonObject;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the testMethod that tries to use the above JSON util object

```java
User user = new User();
user.setBio("bio mate");
user.setCountry("uk");
user.setEmailAddress("jonney@ooglemail.com");
user.setFirstName("jono");
user.setPassword("passwordfdsadsa");
user.setUsername("crazy8");
JSONObject jsonUser =  new JsonParserUtil<User>().toJsonObject(user);
```

User class is a simple POJO with getters and setters. Currently this line: `Method methods[] = T.class.getDeclaredMethods();` won't work, as you can't use the generic T to get the `DeclaredMethods`. Is there a way to do so? Or do I have to create this util method for every single POJO I make?

I know it will work using: `Method methods[] = User.class.getDeclaredMethods();` but that will only be applicable for the User class. I am trying to create a util JSON class that can take any POJO object and try to create a `JSONObject` automatically.

Comment: nevermind. i have fixed the issue. using this:

 public static JSONObject toJsonObject(Object classObject) {
 Method methods[] = classObject.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();

Comment: it's good practice to answer the question, even if its your own question, rather than add a comment with the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
public static JSONObject toJsonObject(Object classObject) {
        // get Method names with @JsonElement included

        Method methods[] = classObject.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
                String key = methods[i].getName();
                System.out.println(key);
                if (methods[i].isAnnotationPresent(JsonElement.class) && key.startsWith(GET_CHAR_SEQUENCE)) {
                    key = key.replaceFirst(GET_CHAR_SEQUENCE, "");
                    jsonObject.put(key, methods[i].invoke(classObject));
                }

            }
            return jsonObject;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
```

The key being to use

```
classObject.getClass()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get class of Class which will return Class itself.

You already have `Class<T> classObject` User class in hand so `classObject.getDeclaredMethods()` should work but you still need the object to serialize or you can pass the User object to be serialized and then get the class type from the object and then serialize it.

Comment: i have provided a solution. i dont need to use generics. i simply ass a Object and then get that Objects class and do my magic. it works. just tested it :)